# How to open a user control as popup using jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have Parts.aspx page,
UserControl1.ascx,[ it contains a textbox and one button1 ]
Add.ascx Controls [ it contains a textbox, button2, button 3 ]
I have added UserControl1.ascx in parts.aspx page.

Now when I click button1 [usercontrol1.ascx] it should open like a popup Add.ascx on top of the page using JQuery Dialog.
In Add.ascx user enters comments in the textbox and clicks Submit, after this it should close Add.ascx and the comments entered in Add.ascx page should appear in UserControl1.ascx textbox for *readonly*.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new page (that is never navigated to, except via the popup), make a jQuery ajax call to retrieve this page, and push the html result into the content of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new aspx page, add user control there.

use the script below @ head of the page

```
<script>

function ShowPopup()
{
   var answer = window.showModalDialog("mypage.aspx","","dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:300px;Center:yes");
}


 </script>

On the button or label click 

<asp:Control ... onClientClick="ShowPopup();"/>
```